# Why this SVG is not being displayed in Google Maps (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I am using SVG files to display icons in the map but one particular SVG doesnt work. I have tested that file and it looks fine in the browser, however, when doing that in the code, it just doesnt display anything , neither it fails:

```
let svgColor = 'red';
let strokeColor = "#00a0d6";

let innerSvg = '<path d="M19.64,16.41a2.07,2.07,0,1,1-2.06,2.06A2.07,2.07,0,0,1,19.64,16.41Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.25,16.41a2.07,2.07,0,1,1-2.06,2.06A2.07,2.07,0,0,1,6.25,16.41Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M9,8.17c-1.55,0-4.5,4.49-4.5,4.49S.68,13.93.68,15.79v2.69H3.44a1.23,1.23,0,0,1,0-.2,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,.29-1.07,2.81,2.81,0,0,1,5.32,1.27h7.78a2.81,2.81,0,0,1,5.31-1.27,2.58,2.58,0,0,1,.29,1,2.36,2.36,0,0,1,0,.25h1.61l.39-.53V8.15S10.51,8.18,9,8.17Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M19.64,19.6a1.13,1.13,0,1,0-1.12-1.13A1.13,1.13,0,0,0,19.64,19.6Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.25,19.6a1.13,1.13,0,1,0-1.12-1.13A1.12,1.12,0,0,0,6.25,19.6Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.26,12.26s2.2-3,2.84-3h3.23v3Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
var svg = '<svg height="40" width="150">' +
    innerSvg +
    '<text x="0" y="7" font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="left" fill="black">Test</text>' +
    '</svg>';

const icon_ = {
    url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 30),
};
return icon_;
```

I have heard before that some SVG complex files are not recognized by Google Service, could it be that case?

I have prepared a jsfiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/9u2kgxth/

**code snippet (from fiddle):**

```js
var map;
var polyLine;
var polyOptions;
var rotation = 0;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    addPoint(event);
  });
}

function addPoint(event) {

  let svgColor = 'red';
  let strokeColor = "#00a0d6";

  let innerSvg = '<path d="M19.64,16.41a2.07,2.07,0,1,1-2.06,2.06A2.07,2.07,0,0,1,19.64,16.41Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.25,16.41a2.07,2.07,0,1,1-2.06,2.06A2.07,2.07,0,0,1,6.25,16.41Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M9,8.17c-1.55,0-4.5,4.49-4.5,4.49S.68,13.93.68,15.79v2.69H3.44a1.23,1.23,0,0,1,0-.2,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,.29-1.07,2.81,2.81,0,0,1,5.32,1.27h7.78a2.81,2.81,0,0,1,5.31-1.27,2.58,2.58,0,0,1,.29,1,2.36,2.36,0,0,1,0,.25h1.61l.39-.53V8.15S10.51,8.18,9,8.17Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M19.64,19.6a1.13,1.13,0,1,0-1.12-1.13A1.13,1.13,0,0,0,19.64,19.6Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.25,19.6a1.13,1.13,0,1,0-1.12-1.13A1.12,1.12,0,0,0,6.25,19.6Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.26,12.26s2.2-3,2.84-3h3.23v3Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  var svg = '<svg height="40" width="150">' +
    innerSvg +
    '<text x="0" y="7" font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="left" fill="black">Test</text>' +
    '</svg>';

  const icon_ = {
    url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 30),
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon
  });

  map.panTo(event.latLng);

  rotation += 10;
}

initialize();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
Click on map to add markers...
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: would have expected it to need to have the SVG namespace defined on the svg root element.

Comment: You have a typo in your fiddle: `Uncaught ReferenceError: icon is not defined`

Comment: @geocodezip fixed the type, thats not the problem eitherway.

Comment: @RobertLongson I really dont understand what you mean

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: @RobertLongson I would never figure it out myself, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<svg>` is missing the namespace (as @RobertLongson indicated in his comment):

```
var svg = '<svg height="40" width="150">' +
    innerSvg +
    '<text x="0" y="7" font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="left" fill="black">Test</text>' +
    '</svg>';
```

should be:

```
var svg = '<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="40" width="150">' +
    innerSvg +
    '<text x="0" y="7" font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="left" fill="black">Test</text>' +
    '</svg>';
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z75qcejv/3/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var polyLine;
var polyOptions;
var rotation = 0;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  addPoint({
    latLng: map.getCenter()
  })

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    addPoint(event);
  });
}

function addPoint(event) {

  let svgColor = 'red';
  let strokeColor = "#00a0d6";

  let innerSvg = '<path d="M19.64,16.41a2.07,2.07,0,1,1-2.06,2.06A2.07,2.07,0,0,1,19.64,16.41Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.25,16.41a2.07,2.07,0,1,1-2.06,2.06A2.07,2.07,0,0,1,6.25,16.41Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M9,8.17c-1.55,0-4.5,4.49-4.5,4.49S.68,13.93.68,15.79v2.69H3.44a1.23,1.23,0,0,1,0-.2,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,.29-1.07,2.81,2.81,0,0,1,5.32,1.27h7.78a2.81,2.81,0,0,1,5.31-1.27,2.58,2.58,0,0,1,.29,1,2.36,2.36,0,0,1,0,.25h1.61l.39-.53V8.15S10.51,8.18,9,8.17Z" style="fill:' + svgColor + ';stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M19.64,19.6a1.13,1.13,0,1,0-1.12-1.13A1.13,1.13,0,0,0,19.64,19.6Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.25,19.6a1.13,1.13,0,1,0-1.12-1.13A1.12,1.12,0,0,0,6.25,19.6Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  innerSvg = innerSvg + '<path d="M6.26,12.26s2.2-3,2.84-3h3.23v3Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:' + strokeColor + ';stroke-miterlimit:1.0800000429153442;stroke-width:0.5400000214576721px"/>';
  var svg = '<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="40" width="150">' +
    innerSvg +
    '<text x="0" y="7" font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="left" fill="black">Test</text>' +
    '</svg>';

  const icon_ = {
    url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 30),
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon_
  });

  map.panTo(event.latLng);

  rotation += 10;
}

initialize();
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
Click on map to add markers...
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: @geocodezip any idea if Google Maps support all kinds of SVG no matter how complex they are? (by implementing them the same way like you have done in this example)

Comment: It should (it is just an icon).  If you have an issue with a particular icon, that would be a new/different question.